# What Internet Explorer 11 security options must be activated to use the button "past from word" on CKEditor 4.5.4

Tags: ckeditor, internet-explorer-11, copy-paste

With Internet Explorer 11, The button "past from word" does not work on ckeditor demo (http://ckeditor.com/demo) : .The content is just directly pasted but not the form.

Do you know what security option could must be activated  to use the button "past from word" on CKEditor 4.5.4 ?

Regads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the CKEditor is configured by default to remove the font styles from the pasted text (it is a desired behaviour in most of the cases).

If you would like to "keep" the styles when pasting from Word, you need to deploy custom configuration for CKEditor.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles=false;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles=false;
}
```